# Highcharts disable Redraw after setExtremes

Tags: highcharts, loader, redraw

I want to disable the chart Redraw event which happens after the setExtremes event . I am talking about even after disabling the liveRedraw ,the chart executes the setExtremes on mouseup after leaving the navigator , then immediately executes the redraw.

I am trying to show a loader on the screen in the setExtremes call but the loader does not appear on the screen. On profiling the same it looks like the paint function to draw on the screen is called only after the Redraw event has finished.

I’d say the flow should be

SetExtremes : 
ShowLoader ()

The loader should now appear on the screen while the chart continues to render the data points then eventually call the Redraw event and then the loader will be hidden after the Redraw event.

Comment: Could you add your code, please?

Comment: To prevent setting extremes you can call preventDefault() or return false inside the setExtremes event callback http://jsfiddle.net/erzLexyg/